# Backup a SQL server localdb with Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, localdb

I am working on a critical inventory project for my firm, and I am facing an issue which I can't seem to solve and is giving me some sleepless nights.

The application is intended to be used on a single computer and we have routine computer formatting. I opted to use localdb as we already lack a dedicated server. **I want to save/backup my localdb and/or the entities' data, and make sure it is tamper proof and be able to restore it later or to a different computer if needed.**

I've tried to copy the .mdf and .ldf files while the connection is closed and restore them when needed, but I not sure this is a good way to do it.

Comment: SQL server (2008 and newer) has a built in function to do that: BACKUP and RESTORE. simply fire the appropriate sql queries.

Comment: I tried doing that but I can't RESTORE. Additionally, after I successfully BACKUP I can't call SaveChanges().

I'll try again and post any errors.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Additionally, is it possible to tamper in the backup files? Do I need to encrypt it?

Comment: I did it this way in my project. Did you remember to connect to the master database in order to restore? Also, backup should be done in a separate context, so no need for SaveChanges() there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the format the standard backup files are in, I'd expect some encrypted T-SQL script - so, if your database file itself is safe, I'd assume the same for the backup file.

Comment: So I need to create a new context to restore, then dispose it, then reconnect my normal context?

Comment: If this is so critical, use an enterprise level database and the best practices that go along with it.

Comment: the context you use to connect to the master database has to be a different context anyways, since the master db most likely does not match the schema and you therefore have to use null initializer, so yeah.

Comment: If it's critical that no one be able to tamper with the backups, encrypt them.  Don't take the word of people on the internet about how secure the backups "should be"; you'll want to ensure their security by using a private key specific to the user or company.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Spot on, thanks for the tip, I'll certainly encrypt it and keep a secret key to the relevant user.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm working under some limitations sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I create my own controller

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class BackupController : Controller
{
private IConfiguration configuration;

```
    public BackupController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        configuration = config;
    }

    public ContentResult Backup()
    {
        try
        {
            var filename = BackupRun();
            return Content($"Backup database successfully to {filename}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("Backup Error database successfully: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public IActionResult BackupAndDownload()
    {
        var filename = BackupRun();
        var content = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename); //NOT USE USING
        var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
        var fileName = $"VideoKurs_{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")}.bak";
        return File(content, contentType, fileName);
    }

    public string BackupRun()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

       //Get Connection String
        sqlcon.ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        //Enter destination directory where backup file stored
        string destdir = "E:\\Backup\\VideoKurs";

        //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") + "\\Backup" ;

        //Check that directory already there otherwise create 
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destdir))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destdir);

        //Open connection
        sqlcon.Open();
        //query to take backup database
        var filename = destdir + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".Bak";
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database [aspnet-SanSoft.Videokurs-D459F243-BB77-45A3-91E6-BD127D86F2C7] to disk='" + filename + "'", sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Close connection
        sqlcon.Close();

        return filename;
    }
}
```